# VBA Excel not responding when copy data to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I use this simple code to copy my sheet from workbook 1 into workbook 2 in the same folder.

```
Sub Button27_Click()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim FileName As String
   Workbooks.Open FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\sefaresh.xlsm"
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Copy
   After:=Workbooks("sefaresh.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The copy&paste function process successfully but if i close the workbook 2 first, i get  not responding for excel. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: try `DoEvents` at the end of your sub.

Comment: i use that before but not works

Comment: try if workbook2 is file corrupt : rename it to a new name, copy all its content (including all code) to a new workbook, save the new wb as the old name of workbook2 , and then try your macro again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (**Untested**). You shouldn't get an error now.

Things become easier if you work with objects :)

```
Sub Button27_Click()
   Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbThat As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim fName As String

   On Error GoTo Whoa

   Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet3")

   fName = wbThis.Path & "\sefaresh.xlsm"

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set wbThat = Workbooks.Open(fName)

   DoEvents 

   ws.Copy After:=wbThat.Sheets(wbThat.Sheets.Count)

   '~~> close and save the workbook
   wbThat.Close (True)

   DoEvents '<~~ Give time for it to save and close

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
   MsgBox Err.Description
   Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: i do this but the same problem. I got the DONE message but after that when iclose the workbook 2 i got not responding.

Comment: Seems like your workbook2 is corrupted. Can you create a new copy of that file by copying across data from this file to a new file. Do not create a copy by directly copy pasting the file.

Comment: I forgot to say this. I have some buttons with macro assign to them in sheet3. this can be problem?

Comment: One moment. My code closes the 2nd workbook in the code. How did it remain open? Did you delete the line `wbThat.Close (True)`

Comment: That was the problem. I copy sheet2 without any button in it with your VBA and its work correctly and close the workbook at last. Now the question become any suggestion to copy sheet with the buttons?

Comment: recreate the buttons :)